# Can I get help re-writing my php code without using session_start? If I need to attach anything else please let me know

Tags: php, session

```
<?php

// Start session
session_start();

$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
if ($action === NULL) {
    $action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
    if ($action === NULL) {
            $action = 'display_login';
    }
}
//instantiate variable(s)
$email = '';

switch ($action) {
    case 'display_login':
        include('customer_login.php');
        break;
    case 'display_register':
        // If customer is not in the session, set it in the session
        if (!isset($_SESSION['customer'])) {
            $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
            $customer = get_customer_by_email($email);
            $_SESSION['customer'] = $customer;
        }

?>
```

Am I able to write this code without using the session_start() function? I have been working to change this without having to use the session_start function but have had a lot of trouble. Is this possible and if so, have I provided enough to do so?

Comment: you definitely need the session_start call. Your code is referencing the $_SESSION superglobal variables, so it has to be started. What issues are you having with the session_start call?

Comment: Yeah, you either have to move your references to $_SESSION to some other variable system, or keep using the sessions

Comment: A better question would be: where did you get this code, and why are you trying to not use the $_SESSION variables that it came with?

Answer (score 1):

SHORT ANSWER: NO.

Session variables are set with the PHP global variable: `$_SESSION`, so you have to use `session_start()` to start a session.

If you don't use `session_start()`, unless you don't use `$_SESSION`.

Comment: In your code, I think the key question is that `if (!isset($_SESSION['customer']))`. If you set the variable `$_SESSION['customer']` somewhere else, you have to use `session_start()`, otherwise you can use an Array or a variable instead of `$_SESSION`